# Is cyclonedx-buildroot expected to generate compatible SBOMs for Dependency-Track?

Tags: owasp, buildroot, sonatype, owasp-dependency-check

I am trying to generate SBOMs for our Buildroot builds and analyze them for vulnerabilities using Dependency-Track.  I am using the Buildroot manifest.csv file and the OWASP tool 'cyclonedx-buildroot' from

https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-buildroot

I can successfully generate a cyclonedx SBOM and post it to dependency-track, but I don't get vulnerability results.  I have the 'internal' and 'Sonatype OSS' analyzers enabled.  They are working successfully for other SBOM's.

Looking into this further, here is a package url generated from the Buildroot manifest using cyclonedx-buildroot

pkg:generic/busybox@1.35.0?download_url=https://www.busybox.net/downloadsbusybox-1.35.0.tar.bz2

Using the SonaType API with that package url doesn't return any CVEs.  Using the Sonatype web search utility, I can see that there is no 'generic' type and the version strings are different.  Here is an example that returns CVEs successfully by specifying the rpm type and a specific rpm version.

pkg:rpm/busybox@1:1.35.0-2.el9

My expectation was that the OWASP cyclonedx-buildroot tool would generate SBOMs with package url's (or CPEs) that Dependency-Track (also OWASP) would be able to analyze.  Am I missing something? Is anyone successfully generating SBOMs based on a Buildroot manifest that can be analyzed by Dependency-Track.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer for the Buildroot interface to CycloneDX. I see you added your request to my github repo of features, perfect.
I recognize that there is a large difference in the URL data produced by Buildroot and the capabilities of other tools including CycloneDX, so I am facing limitations that are built-in.
From my perspective the url in the above format (pkg:generic/busybox@1.35.0?download_url=https://www.busybox.net/downloadsbusybox-1.35.0.tar.bz2) is exactly what I can parse from the Buildroot manifest file. I do not use Sonatype, the Buildroot embedded word does not use RPM package management so for now, this will be a feature request. Thanks!
https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-buildroot/issues/12